# QML runtime enivronment not found

Tags: qt, qml, runtime, qt5.4

There are a few questions similar to this on Stackoverflow but none of them really answers clearly. I have QT version 5 (64-bit windows). I have just started learning QML but don't know how to run it. The website says that a QML runtime environment should be provided and it is installed with the QT itself. But there is no QML runtime environment on my computer. How to provide this environment manually?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Qt document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#:%7E:text=The%20QML%20runtime%20loads%20QML,file%20for%20each%20QML%20document.) says,

> Applications that use QML must invoke the QML runtime to run QML
> documents. You can do this by creating a QQuickView or a QQmlEngine.
> In addition, the Declarative UI package includes the qmlscene tool,
> which loads .qml files. This tool is useful for developing and testing
> QML code without having to write a C++ application to load the QML
> runtime.

You can only write a simple qml file and run it with qmlscene.exe.

`hello.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello, QML!"
    }
}
```

From cmd you can execute `%qt_dir%/%qt_version%/%platform%/bin/qmlscene.exe` For my own environment `C:\Qt\5.12.8\msvc2017_64\bin\qmlscene.exe hello.qml` resulted like

[image]

cheers